# Difference between having and not having parenthesis in if statements

Tags: python

In the python, the `if` statement can have parentheses or not like this:

```
if True:
    pass

if (True):
    pass
```

Is there any difference at all, even a performance difference, between these?

Comment: The second one is ugly; the first is not.

Comment: Literally no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiled byte codes show,

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(compile("if True: pass", "string", "exec"))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis(compile("if (True): pass", "string", "exec"))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

there is no difference between them at all. There are two things which I can think of.

1. You may want to use parens when you want to logically group conditions. For example,

   ```
   if 10/5 == 2 and 2*5 == 10:
       pass
   ```

   would look better as

   ```
   if (10/5 == 2) and (2*5 == 10):
       pass
   ```
2. You can make the conditions more like English sentences by avoiding parens wherever possible.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, parenthesis are not required. You usually use them to group long complex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As in most languages, extra parentheses are ignored. In Python the `if` statement doesn't require any at all. Both statements are identical.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to keep in mind is grouping conditionals.

Including conditionals in parentheses can change the intended ordering slightly:

```
x = True
y = True
z = True

if x==False and y==False or z==True:
    print 'foo'  # This will print

if x==False and (y==False or z==True):
    print 'bar'  # This will not print
```

The first statement should be read as `if (x==False and y==False) or z==True:`